# Rocky Linux 8.8: memory leak in threads when dynamic allocations are performed before they are launched

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, rocky-os

In Rocky Linux 8.8 (9.2 also), have you ever encountered a memory leak problem in threads when dynamic allocations are performed before they are launched?
See the code below

If in this same code (test, not clean), I don't do dynamic allocations or smaller ones, there is no memory leak.
With top, htop, for a certain period of time (20 minutes, 1 hour), depending on the size of the memory available on the machine, no memory leak is observed, then all of a sudden the memory increases until it reaches a ceiling.

Note that this source does not cause memory leaks on Ubuntu 18.4.

Thanks a lot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>



bool g_stop = false;


void* func(const int id) {  
    std::cout << "Start of thread " << id << std::endl;

    while(!g_stop)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "Wait for thread " << id << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "End of thread " << id << std::endl;

    return nullptr;
}

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 65535

int main()
{
    ///////////// Wihtout this dynamic allocation no memory leak
    for(int i = 0; i < 6000; ++i)
    {
        new char[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::thread* pt = new std::thread(func,i+1);
    }

    std::cout<< "Press key to stop threads" << std::endl;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    g_stop = true;

    std::cout<< "Press key to exit"  << std::endl;

    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

With top, htop, for a certain period of time (20 minutes, 1 hour), depending on the size of the memory available on the machine, no memory leak is observed, then all of a sudden the memory increases until it reaches a ceiling.